# How can I display the members of a group?

Tags: contacts, groups

I would like to go into a group to see who is listed in it, please advise how I can view a group. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

There's more than one way to view the contacts added to a group, here are a few, all of them will list the contacts belonging to the searched group.

Option 1) Navigate to **Search -> Find Contacts**, select your group filling the field ***in any group***, leave the rest of the fields blank and hit search.

Option 2) Navigate to **Search -> Advanced Search**, select your group from the **Groups** field and hit search.

Option 3) Navigate to **Contacts -> Manage Groups**, here you can search/create/delete groups, on the right hand side of the screen there's a ***Contacts*** button for each created group, click it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways, here are two options:

- If you go to the Contacts menu option, there hit the Manage Groups
  option you get a list of all groups. Behind each group is a Contacts
  option, hit that you get all members.
- If you go to the Search menu and select Find Contacts, you can select a group there and the result will be all members of that group

Answer (score 2):

**Using API Explorer** -

1) Navigate to `Support -> Developer -> Api Explorer`

2) Select Entity as `GroupContact` Action `get`

3) select your group as parameter -> Execute

Eg :

```
$result = civicrm_api3('GroupContact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'group_id' => "Advisory Board",
));
```